# Trouble Using Subqueries Properly (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm trying to wrap my head around subqueries, and for the most part have been having success in different contexts. This one, however, has me stumped.

I have a timesheet table that holds regular hours and overtime hours worked for two pay periods. It shares an employee ID key with my employees table.

What I'm trying to check for is who has worked over 80 total hours between both pay periods, then display their name + payrate.

The code below is wrong, but any changes I've made to try and get it to work result in errors.

```
SELECT Employee.Lastname, Job.Payrate * 1.05 "Increased"
FROM Employee JOIN Job
ON Employee.Jobcode = Job.Jobcode
WHERE EmpID IN (SELECT SUM(Reghours + Otimehours) FROM Timesheet GROUP BY EmpID);
```

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? If more context is needed please let me know.

This is for my prior problem in which I was only looking for > 40 hours worked in one pay period. I tried editing this one to have it work but I think I'm overlooking something simple.

```
SELECT Employee.Lastname, ROUND(Job.Payrate * 1.05, 2) "Increased"
FROM Employee JOIN Job
ON Employee.Jobcode = Job.Jobcode
WHERE EmpID IN (SELECT EmpID FROM Timesheet WHERE Payweekenddate = '30-MAY-03' AND Reghours + Otimehours > 40);
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make your problem much simpler for others to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing to check EMPID in sub-query -

```
SELECT Employee.Lastname, Job.Payrate * 1.05 "Increased"
FROM Employee JOIN Job
ON Employee.Jobcode = Job.Jobcode
WHERE EmpID IN (SELECT EmpID 
                FROM Timesheet
                GROUP BY EmpID
                HAVING SUM(Reghours + Otimehours) >= 80 );
```